# .NET CORE List properties of an attribute

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple classes that use this custom attribute. All of them implement the same interface and they all have this custom attribute and have different names

```
public class NameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public NameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Is there a way to return a list of these names in the controller?

Comment: List of values of that property? please explain what is meant by that?

Comment: In the controller i want to return a list of names from the attribute

Comment: its  string variable, so wither store the values as comma separated values the split and send

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to access the name properties from the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for if someone has the same problem in the future. This is what I did:

```
        IEnumerable<Type> types = typeof(Startup).Assembly.ExportedTypes
            .Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
            .Where(type => type.GetInterface("IName") != null)
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttribute<NameAttribute>() != null);

        List<string> rules = new List<string>();

        foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            rules.Add(t.GetCustomAttribute<NameAttribute>().Name);
        }
```

Basicly what happens is that I look for all the exported types that implement an interface named "IName" and have the "NameAttribute" attribute. This will return a enumerable list with types.

Next it is possible to retrieve the custom attribute and put the name in an arraylist.